# Task "concat" not found in Grunt on windows

Tags: gruntjs

My gruntfile :

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {
        js: {
            src: ['http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', 'js/bootstrap.min.js', 'js/messages.fr.js', 'js/parsley.min.js'],
            dest: 'js/prod/concat.js'
        },
        css: {
            src: ['css/bootstrap.min.css', 'css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css', 'css/app.css'],
            dest: 'css/prod/concat.css'
        }
    },

    min: {
        js: {
            src: 'js/prod/concat.js',
            dest: 'js/prod/main.min.js'
        }
    },

    cssmin: {
        minify: {
            expand: true,
            src: ['css/prod/concat.css', '!*.min.css'],
            dest: 'css/prod/',
            ext: '.min.css'
        }
    }

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin', 'grunt-contrib-cssmin');

// Default task.
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'min', 'cssmin']);
```

};

No matter what I try (removing task, etc) grunt keeps coming at me with the same message "Warning: Task "concat" not found". It's the same if I remove concat : "Warning: Task "min" not found".

I do not understand what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Older versions of Gruntjs contained some default tasks, like concat and min. Starting with Grunt 0.4 you have to add all the tasks (plugins) you want yourself. I believe that for both minification and concatenation you can use a task like [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify).

Please make sure you're running the latest version of Grunt. A lot of online available tutorials mention Grunt 0.3, but a lot has changed since then. For example, tutorials mentioning grunt.js (Grunt 0.3) instead of Gruntfile.js (0.4) are obsolete in a lot of ways.

Answer (score 7):

This just happened to me. Its also important to make sure that after you have `npm`-installed a grunt task, you've also registered it in your Gruntfile.

So the end of your gruntfile should have `loadNpmTasks` lines kinda like so:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

// Default task.
grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'concat', 'uglify']);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old but I just got this error too and found that it was caused by not having any of the source files (specified in concat.dist.src within gruntfile.js) where they were meant to be. I placed the files where grunt expected them and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem but I try this and my problem has solved.
try this command in your node.js command prompt.

npm install grunt-contrib-concat --save-dev