# Grunt does not find the lint task

Tags: gruntjs

I've inherited a project that was managed with Grunt (in fact with an old version, I'm not sure exactly which) and I am a total newbie to it.

I've made a two changes that seemed logical by reading the documentation (I guess to conform to the latest specification): converting tasks list that were in a single string delimited by white spaces to proper lists.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        meta: {
            banner: '/*! <%= pkg.title || pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
                '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>\n' +
                '<%= pkg.homepage ? "* " + pkg.homepage + "\n" : "" %>' +
                '* Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= pkg.author.name %>;' +
                ' Licensed <%= _.pluck(pkg.licenses, "type").join(", ") %> */'
        },
        handlebars: {
            all: {
                src: 'src/templates/',
                dest: 'dist/templates.js'
            }
        },
        require : {
            all: {
                src : 'src/scripts/app.build.js',
                dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
            }
        },
        concat: {
            dist: {
                src: ['<file_strip_banner:src/scripts/bootstrap.js>', '<file_strip_banner:dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js>'],
                dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
            }
        },
        min: {
            dist: {
                src: ['<config:concat.dist.dest>'],
                dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
            }
        },
        qunit: {
            files: [
                'test/**/*.html',
                'test/**/*.js'
            ]
        },
        lint : {
            browser : [
                'grunt.js',
                'src/scripts/*.js',
                'src/scripts/storage/**/*.js',
                'src/scripts/util/*.js',
                'test/**/*.js',
                'src/templates/helpers/*.js'
            ],
            node : [
                'build/**/*.js',
                'tasks/**/*.js'
            ]
        },
        watch: {
            files: [
                // '<config:handlebars.src>',
                '<config:lint.browser>',
                '<config:qunit.files>'
                ],
            tasks: ['lint', 'handlebars', 'require']
        },
        jshint : {
            browser : {
                options : {
                    curly: true,
                    eqeqeq: true,
                    immed: true,
                    latedef: true,
                    newcap: true,
                    noarg: true,
                    sub: true,
                    undef: true,
                    boss: true,
                    eqnull: true,
                    browser: true
                },
                globals : {
                    JQuery: false,
                    Handlebars: false,
                    templates: false
                }
            },
            node : {
                options : {
                    esnext : true,
                    strict : false
                },
                globals : {
                    module : true,
                    require : true,
                    setTimeout : true,
                    Buffer : true,
                    process : true
                }
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            'overwrite': true,
            'unsafe': true,
            'lift-vars': true
        }
    });

    grunt.loadTasks('tasks');

    // Default task.
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['lint', 'handlebars', 'require', 'concat', 'min']);

};
```

When I run `grunt` this is the message that I get:

```
Warning: Task "lint" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

And there's clearly a `lint` task defined in the config.

Any ideas of what might be failing?

Comment: The lint object that's passed into `grunt.initConfig()` is not defining a lint task, it's just supplying config for the lint task. `grunt.loadTasks('tasks');` is what would load your local tasks. Is there a lint.js task within the '/tasks' directory?

Comment: Now that you say... There's only a `handlebarsTask.js` and a `requireTask.js`

Comment: It looks like you've inherited a broken grunt build system. Essentially, the tasks are missing. You can either define 'local' tasks (examples being the tasks you listed), or you can load npm modules as grunt tasks. Did this grunt setup ever work prior to you inheriting this code?

Comment: I think so, the other member of my team used it (although he wasn't the one that created it in the first place)

Comment: Perhaps the tasks weren't committed to the repo, or something along those lines. The problem is simple, as the error states, tasks are missing. You'll either need to find those tasks or create them yourself. I suggest speaking to the other team member.

Comment: The other guy is as clueless as I am... I think I'm in the way to fix it, adding the `loadNpmTask` lines and installing the required plugins as described in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946224/task-concat-not-found-in-grunt-on-windows?rq=1

Comment: That makes sense! Here's a list of npm tasks that you can use to replace the old default tasks: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Upgrading-from-0.3-to-0.4#core-tasks-are-now-grunt-plugins

Comment: @badsyntax nice link! if you want to use that as an answer I'd be glad to accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Older versions of Grunt (v0.3) contained a set of default tasks. The eight core tasks that were included in Grunt 0.3 are now separate Grunt plugins, as of Grunt 0.4.

So the `lint`, `concat` and `min` tasks will need to defined. You can load these tasks using [grunt.loadNpmTasks](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt#grunt.loadnpmtasks)

Here's a list of plugins you can use to replace the default tasks: http://gruntjs.com/upgrading-from-0.3-to-0.4#core-tasks-are-now-grunt-plugins