# Tasks and sub-tasks not found

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I just started using Grunt and I already may have a problem. So, here is what my `Gruntfile.js` looks like :

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Ability to access the package.json informations
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    // SASS compilation
    sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'compressed'
        },
        expand: true,
        cwd: './sass/',
        src: 'main.scss',
        dest: './css/',
        ext: '.css'
      },
      dev: {
        options: {
          style: 'expanded',
          debugInfo: true,
          lineNumbers: true
        },
        expand: true,
        cwd: './sass/',
        src: 'main.scss',
        dest: './css/',
        ext: '.css'
      }
    }

  });
};
```

And when I run `grunt sass:dev`, it always returns me `Warning: Task "sass:dev" not found. Use --force to continue.`

As I'm starting with it, I took a look at the doc and can't find where I may have gone wrong... And yes, dependencies are correctly installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Task "concat" not found in Grunt on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946224/task-concat-not-found-in-grunt-on-windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure the task is registered, after the initConfig section.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    // ...
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
};
```

Comment: Ok ok ! I didn't got I had to do for each task not called in a custom one. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. Although, depending on the amount of plugins you are using, you may want to use something like load-grunt-tasks (https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks) instead, so you can have `require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);` rather than a long list of all your dependencies. :)